# 2-Player Tank Battle Game

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've created a 2-player tank battle game. The code however seems like it could be greatly simplified and there are a few issues. One of which is the hitboxes of the tank seem a bit unreliable. Sometimes when a bullet is fired, it will hit the empty space next to a tank and count as a hit, but other times it will pass straight through the tank.

This is using Pygame for Python 3.6.3. This program is a modification of a program shown in "More Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner" by Jonathon Harbour (Chapter 12). I’m looking for ways to improve and simplify my program.

```
# Tank 2-Player Battle Game

import sys, time, random, math, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from My_Library import *

class Bullet():
    def __init__(self, position):
        self.alive = True
        self.color = (250, 20, 20)
        self.position = Point(position.x, position.y)
        self.velocity = Point(0, 0)
        self.rect = Rect(0, 0, 4, 4)
        self.owner = ""

    def update(self, ticks):
        self.position.x -= self.velocity.x * 10.0
        self.position.y -= self.velocity.y * 10.0
        if self.position.x < 0 or self.position.x > 800 \
           or self.position.y < 0 or self.position.y > 600:
            self.alive = False
        self.rect = Rect(self.position.x, self.position.y, 4, 4)

    def draw(self, surface):
        pos = (int(self.position.x), int(self.position.y))
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, self.color, pos, 4, 0)

def fire_cannon(tank):
    position = Point(tank.turret.X, tank.turret.Y)
    bullet = Bullet(position)
    angle = tank.turret.rotation + 90
    bullet.velocity = angular_velocity(angle)
    bullets.append(bullet)
    play_sound(shoot_sound)
    return bullet

def player_fire_cannon():
    bullet = fire_cannon(player)
    bullet.owner = "player"
    bullet.color = (30, 250, 30)

def player2_fire_cannon():
    bullet = fire_cannon(player2)
    bullet.owner = "player2"
    bullet.color = (250, 30, 30)

class Tank(MySprite):
    def __init__(self, tank_file, turret_file):
        MySprite.__init__(self)
        self.load(tank_file, 50, 60, 4)
        self.speed = 0.0
        self.scratch = None
        self.float_pos = Point(0, 0)
        self.velocity = Point(0, 0)
        self.turret = MySprite()
        self.turret = MySprite()
        self.turret.load(turret_file, 32, 64, 4)
        self.fire_timer = 0

    def update(self,ticks):
        # update chassis
        MySprite.update(self, ticks, 100)
        self.rotation = wrap_angle(self.rotation)
        self.scratch = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, -self.rotation)
        angle = wrap_angle(self.rotation-90)
        self.velocity = angular_velocity(angle)
        self.float_pos.x += self.velocity.x * 2
        self.float_pos.y += self.velocity.y * 2

        # warp tank around screen edges (keep it simple)
        if self.float_pos.x < -50: self.float_pos.x = 800
        elif self.float_pos.x > 800: self.float_pos.x = -50
        if self.float_pos.y < -60: self.float_pos.y = 600
        elif self.float_pos.y > 600: self.float_pos.y = -60

        # transfer float position to integer position for drawing
        self.X = int(self.float_pos.x)
        self.Y = int(self.float_pos.y)

        # update turret
        self.turret.position = (self.X, self.Y)
        self.turret.last_frame = 0
        self.turret.update(ticks, 100)
        self.turret.rotation = wrap_angle(self.turret.rotation)
        angle = wrap_angle(self.turret.rotation)
        self.turret.scratch = pygame.transform.rotate(self.turret.image, -angle)

    def draw(self, surface):
        # draw the chassis
        width, height = self.scratch.get_size()
        center = Point(width/2, height/2)
        surface.blit(self.scratch, (self.X-center.x, self.Y-center.y))        
        # draw the turret
        width, height = self.turret.scratch.get_size()
        center = Point(width/2, height/2)
        surface.blit(self.turret.scratch, (self.turret.X-center.x,
                                           self.turret.Y-center.y))

    def __str__(self):
        return MySprite.__str__(self) + "," + str(self.velocity)

# this function initializes the game
def game_init():
    global screen, backbuffer, font, timer, player_group, player, \
           player2, bullets

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    backbuffer = pygame.Surface((800, 600))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Tank Battle Game")
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    # create player tank
    player = Tank("tank.png", "turret.png")
    player.float_pos = Point(400, 300)

    # create second player tank
    player2 = Tank("enemy_tank.png", "enemy_turret.png")
    player2.float_pos = Point(random.randint(50, 760), 50)

    # create bullets
    bullets = list()

# this function initializes the audio system
def audio_init():
    global shoot_sound, boom_sound

    # initialize the audio mixer
    pygame.mixer.init()

    # load sound files
    shoot_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("shoot.wav")
    boom_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("boom.wav")

# this function uses any available channel to play a sound clip
def play_sound(sound):
    channel = pygame.mixer.find_channel(True)
    channel.set_volume(0.5)
    channel.play(sound)

# main program begins
game_init()
audio_init()
game_over = False
player_score = 0
player2_score = 0
last_time = 0
action1 = False
action2 = False
action3 = False
action4 = False
action5 = False
action6 = False

# main loop
while True:
    timer.tick(30)
    ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # event section
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                action1 = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                action2 = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                action3 = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                action4 = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                action5 = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                action6 = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                action1 = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                action2 = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                action3 = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                action4 = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                action5 = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                action6 = False

    if action1 == True:
        player.rotation -= 4.0
        player.turret.rotation -= 4.0
    if action2 == True:
        player.rotation += 4.0
        player.turret.rotation += 4.0
    if action3 == True:
        player2.rotation -= 4.0
        player2.turret.rotation -= 4.0
    if action4 == True:
        player2.rotation += 4.0
        player2.turret.rotation += 4.0
    if action5 == True:
        if ticks > player.fire_timer + 1000:
            player.fire_timer = ticks
            player_fire_cannon()
    if action6 == True:
        if ticks > player2.fire_timer + 1000:
            player2.fire_timer = ticks
            player2_fire_cannon()


    # update section
    if not game_over:
        # move tank
        player.update(ticks)

        # update player two
        player2.update(ticks)

        # update bullets
        for bullet in bullets:
                bullet.update(ticks)
                if bullet.owner == "player":
                    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(bullet, player2):
                        player_score += 1
                        bullet.alive = False
                        play_sound(boom_sound)
                elif bullet.owner == "player2":
                    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(bullet, player):
                        player2_score += 1
                        bullet.alive = False
                        play_sound(boom_sound)

    # drawing section
    backbuffer.fill((100, 100, 20))

    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(backbuffer)

    player.draw(backbuffer)

    player2.draw(backbuffer)

    screen.blit(backbuffer, (0, 0))

    if not game_over:
        print_text(font, 0, 0, "PLAYER 1: " + str(player_score))
        print_text(font, 650, 0, "PLAYER 2: " + str(player2_score))
    else:
        print_text(font, 0, 0, "GAME OVER")

    pygame.display.update()

    # remove expired bullets
    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.alive == False:
            bullets.remove(bullet)
```

Here is the My_Library file that is imported at the beginning:

```
# MyLibrary.py
import sys, time, random, math, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# calculates velocity of an angle
def angular_velocity(angle):
    vel = Point(0, 0)
    vel.x = math.cos( math.radians(angle) )
    vel.y = math.sin( math.radians(angle) )
    return vel

# calculates angle between two points
def target_angle(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    delta_x = x2 - x1
    delta_y = y2 - y1
    angle_radians = math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x)
    angle_degrees = math.degrees(angle_radians)
    return angle_degrees

# wraps a degree angle at boundary
def wrap_angle(angle):
    return abs(angle % 360)

# prints text using the supplied font
def print_text(font, x, y, text, color = (255, 255, 255)):
    imgText = font.render(text, True, color)
    screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
    screen.blit(imgText, (x, y))

# MySprite class extends pygame.sprite.Sprite
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) # extend the base Sprite class
        self.master_image = None
        self.frame = 0
        self.old_frame = -1
        self.frame_width = 1
        self.frame_height = 1
        self.first_frame = 0
        self.last_frame = 0
        self.columns = 1
        self.last_time = 0
        self.direction = 0
        self.velocity = Point(0, 0)
        self.rotation = 0.0 # degrees # added
        self.old_rotation = 0.0 # added

    # X property
    def _getx(self): return self.rect.x
    def _setx(self, value): self.rect.x = value
    X = property(_getx, _setx)

    # Y property
    def _gety(self): return self.rect.y
    def _sety(self, value): self.rect.y = value
    Y = property(_gety, _sety)

    # position property
    def _getpos(self): return self.rect.topleft
    def _setpos(self, pos): self.rect.topleft = pos
    position = property(_getpos, _setpos)

    def load(self, filename, width, height, columns):
        self.master_image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
        self.frame_width = width
        self.frame_height = height
        self.rect = Rect(0, 0, width, height)
        self.columns = columns
        # try to auto-calculate total frames
        rect = self.master_image.get_rect()
        self.last_frame = (rect.width // width) * (rect.height // height) - 1

    def update(self, current_time, rate=30):
        if self.last_frame > self.first_frame:
            # update animation frame number
            if current_time > self.last_time + rate:
                self.frame += 1
                if self.frame > self.last_frame:
                    self.frame = self.first_frame
                self.last_time = current_time
        else:
            self.frame = self.first_frame

        # build current frame only if it changed
        if self.frame != self.old_frame:
            frame_x = (self.frame % self.columns) * self.frame_width
            frame_y = (self.frame // self.columns) * self.frame_height
            rect = Rect(frame_x, frame_y, self.frame_width, self.frame_height)
            self.image = self.master_image.subsurface(rect)
            self.old_frame = self.frame

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.frame) + "," + str(self.first_frame) + \
               "," + str(self.last_frame) + "," + str(self.frame_width) + \
               "," + str(self.frame_height) + "," + str(self.columns) + \
               "," + str(self.rect)

    def load(self, filename, width = 0, height = 0, columns = 1):
        self.master_image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
        self.set_image(self.master_image, width, height, columns)

    def set_image(self, image, width = 0, height = 0, columns = 1):
        self.master_image = image
        if width == 0 and height == 0:
            self.frame_width = image.get_width()
            self.frame_height = image.get_height()
        else:
            self.frame_width = width
            self.frame_height = height
            rect = self.master_image.get_rect()
            self.last_frame = (rect.width//width) * (rect.height//height) - 1
        self.rect = Rect(0, 0, self.frame_width, self.frame_height)
        self.columns = columns

# Point class
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y

    # X property
    def getx(self): return self.__x
    def setx(self, x): self.__x = x
    x = property(getx, setx)

    # Y property
    def gety(self): return self.__y
    def sety(self, y): self.__y = y
    y = property(gety, sety)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{X:" + "{:.0f}".format(self.__x) + \
               ",Y:" + "{:.0f}".format(self.__y) + "}"
```

Comment: Is there a repo with the other files?

Comment: All of the other files are built into python and pygame. I don’t know a lot about their inner workings, but the information can all be found on the internet. Here’s a link to the pygame website: https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/ImportInit.html

Comment: It wouldn’t let me edit my comment further, but I found the link to the Python repository: https://pypi.org/search/?q=time

Comment: Are the bullets supposed to be rectangular or circular? You're drawing them as circles, yet checking for intersection as rectangular.

Comment: The bullets are supposed to be circular.

Comment: What are you expecting from the community? Explaining and fixing your code? I would consider this as [off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for Code Review. If you want feedback on your code in general, then your [good to go](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Alex I just want general feedback on my code. However, I’m pointing out one of the main issues I’m looking to fix. I already have a working game. I’m only trying to improve it. If I came across as wanting someone to just explain and fix my code then I apologize.

Comment: @MuckinAround145 The file(s) I was asking about are things like `tank.png`. I'm trying to run your code, and it has all these demands...

Comment: @AustinHastings Here’s a link to the files. If you download them the tank.png and other pictures should be in the chapter 12 folder. http://www.delmarlearning.com/companions/content/1435455002/downloads/index.asp?isbn=1435455002

Comment: @MuckinAround145: Unfortunately changing what your code does is off-topic here. The general feedback part, however is very much on-topic. I would recommend you remove the part about seeking help fixing the hitboxes. You might want to mention that there is currently a problem with them, but that this can be ignored. This would make the question on-topic IMO.

Answer (score 5):

You have provided a lot of code, and it's not super well organized. So I'm going to focus on that, plus some things I noticed in passing. There's probably enough for another review once you incorporate what you learn from this one.

First, you have some good ideas. Moving "basic" things into a library is a good idea. Using classes is a good idea. Breaking your conceptually related statements into functions is a good idea. For the most part, you are on target with what you are doing and how you are doing it.

Now for the not-most part: ;-)

## PEP 8

You code isn't PEP-8 in a lot of ways. Some of them are harmful, and some are just irritating. `My_Library` is irritating *and* harmful: not every filesystem is case-aware, so you can't depend on caps; and the name is useless. Either name it something application related (tank_library) or something platform related (pygame_utils).

### Comments

Comments are funny things. Most coding classes try to encourage you to use them, but don't provide you with enough of a challenge to actually *need* them. So they encourage you to put in worthless comments, just to get in the habit. That appears to have happened to you. Consider this:

```
# MySprite class extends pygame.sprite.Sprite
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
```

This is a classic "worthless comment." The comment merely says in English exactly what the code says in the syntax of Python. It's right up there with

```
x = x + 1  # add 1 to x
```

You should delete any comment like this, since it provides no value presently, and might eventually drift into being wrong and providing negative value.

Now consider this:

```
# prints text using the supplied font
def print_text(font, x, y, text, color = (255, 255, 255)):
```

This is almost a worthless comment. But it's also almost a useful comment. Except that there are no useful comments on functions. What you want is to make this into a **useful docstring:**

```
def print_text(...etc...):
    ''' Display text on screen at position (x, y) using font & color. '''
```

Even more useful would be to specify what position (x, y) means. Is that the top left, bottom left, the center, the baseline? Also, color is semi-obvious since you provide a default, but how about font? Is that a string name, or a Font object, or ... ?

The nice thing about docstrings is that you can write as much as you want, and it can be nicely useful in a lot of ways, including just doing `help(print_text)` in the REPL. Comments, not so much.

Finally, consider this:

```
# transfer float position to integer position for drawing
self.X = int(self.float_pos.x)
self.Y = int(self.float_pos.y)
```

This seems like a useful comment. It explains too much of what you're doing -- after all, I can see you are converting from float to int. But it does explain *why* you are doing something non-obvious. That provides some value.

(Note: the presence of `.X` as an integer drawable version of `.x` might not *have* value, per se. But the comment has value, since it makes clear something that wouldn't be clear otherwise.)

### Organization

#### Class Bullet

Class `Bullet` has an `update` and a `draw` method, but it is not a subclass of anything:

```
class Bullet():
    def __init__(self, position): ...
    def update(self, ticks): ...
    def draw(self, surface): ...
```

If it's not a subclass, you can drop the parentheses after the name. But it probably should be a subclass, either of `Sprite` or `MySprite`. Pygame provides sprite groups to do what you are doing manually. You should put your bullets into one.

#### Class Tank

Now this:

```
def fire_cannon(tank):
    ...

def player_fire_cannon():
    bullet = fire_cannon(player)
    ...

def player2_fire_cannon():
    bullet = fire_cannon(player2)
    ...

class Tank(MySprite):
```

If only there were some mechanism whereby you could write a function that would have access to a collection of related data... Oh, wait! You could make `fire_cannon` a method of class `Tank`.

```
def __init__(self, tank_file, turret_file):
    MySprite.__init__(self)

def update(self,ticks):
    # update chassis
    MySprite.update(self, ticks, 100)
```

The built-in function you are looking for here is [`super()`](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

And speaking of the `update` method: delegate! You Tank has a chassis and a turret, and they get drawn differently. So make the turret (or the chassis) a separate sprite, and "manage" it from the Tank class.

You might even consider making *both* of them separate sprites, and having the Tank be invisible or not a sprite at all. This would be the difference between "is-a" sprite and "has-a" sprite. If the tank is just a holder for a collection of other sprites (and a central position), a lot of your code probably gets shorter because the classes can handle it.

#### Pygame

You need Pygame in both your library and your main file. Consider trying to push all the explicit pygame dependencies into a single file, and your non-pygame dependencies into the other file. This won't actually result in an app/library distribution, but it might help you to identify "pure" objects that you can optimize in different ways.

#### class Point

This is horrible:

```
self.position = Point(position.x, position.y)
```

If `position` is a Point, why can't you just either refer to it, or initialize a new one using an instance of the same class?

```
self.position = position
# or
from copy import copy
self.position = copy(position)
# or
self.position = Point(position)
```

In fact, I'd suggest that you use `namedtuple` for your point class. It's built-in, and it does almost everything you want:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
p1 = Point(123, 456)
p2 = Point(*p1)
```

Note the "splat:"  `*p1`. Or you could *inherit* from the named tuple and provide your own `__new__` method which does the splatting for you:

```
def __new__(cls, p_or_x, y=None):
    if isinstance(p_or_x, cls):
        # New Point from old Point
        return super().__new__(cls, *p_or_x)
    else:
        # New Point from x, y
        return super().__new__(cls, p_or_x, y)
```

Speaking of PEP 8: please don't use __x and __y unless you know that you need to. (You don't.) Names that start with double underscores, other than the special "dunder" names, are "mangled" internally. That's great for solving a specific problem, but you don't have that problem. Just use `x` until you have a property method, then switch to `_x`.

Here are some unrelated lines of code:

```
    self.position.x -= self.velocity.x * 10.0
    self.position.y -= self.velocity.y * 10.0
    pos = (int(self.position.x), int(self.position.y))
```

If you have a look at the "dunder methods" available, you will find that it's possible to implement things like scalar multiplication and in-place subtraction. You might even find a way to `trunc`ate values ;-)

```
from math import trunc

def __trunc__(self):
    return self.__class__(trunc(self.x), trunc(self.y))
```